# I'll be going or I will be get going?

Tags: word-choice

Which form is correct? I'll be going or I will be get going or I will get going?

Comment: What do you want to express? "I'll be going" and "I will get going" are both grammatical, but there are probably some minor differences in meaning. "I will be get going" is not correct. "I will be getting going" would be correct, if a bit wordy.

Comment: 'I'll get going' can mean 'I'll start [the job etc that context indicates]' as well as 'I'll get off'.